# Is this the correct way to access objects inside a list?

Tags: c++, list

EDIT: **TLDR?** Here's a summary:

The requirement is for an essentially infinitely (or arbitrarily) long container. So list sounds like a good idea, because it will fit the objects in whatever memory space is available.

However vectors are much faster/efficient at access, but might not be able to fit in memory if we don't have a long sequential strip.

Vector of pointers was suggested to reduce memory usage, but the problem remains if there are a gigabyte of pointers and I have 4GB of ram, it might just not fit!

Solution: A list of vectors might be the way to go. Each item in the list could be a vector with 1000 pointers to items which we want to be able to access. A class could handle this functionality.

** Original Question:**

As a wise man once said: "With pointers, if it works once, that doesn't guarantee you are doing it correctly."

I have a class:

```
class A;
```

And class A is inside a std::list:

```
std::list<A> list_of_A;
```

To access items inside it I am using:

```
std::list<A>::iterator iter = list_of_A.begin();
std::advance(iter, <an_unsigned_int>);
return *iter;
```

This seems to be working, but is `return *iter` the correct thing to be doing? I should mention the last 3 lines are inside a function which returns a `const A&`.

I looked for an answer on stackoverflow, but couldn't find a duplicate of this question, which surprises me.

List > Vector because I will be swapping things in and out of the list.

Comment: Its correct, if its working why ask?

Comment: Pointers: Just because it works once, doesn't mean you are doing it correctly.

Comment: Yes, but if you find yourself doing that often, you might prefer to use a different data structure. One with random access iterators, e.g. `std::vector`. Stepping over a list is O(N), accessing an element of a vector in a similar fashion is constant time.

Comment: The importance here is insertion and removal.

Comment: if you need to access list element by index, you should be thinking about switching to vector alike.

Comment: Okay, guys, I am not going to use a vector. That will take a year to insert a new item into the middle of it if it has over 500 items.

Comment: @EdwardBird Have you profiled it? Are you inserting in the middle? I would conject that a vector is still more performant in many cases. Your objects must be huge if you've got performance problems at 500 items.

Comment: @EdwardBird, stop and do benchmarks before you go any further. On modern hardware vector will often be faster at inserting/removing because it fits cache nicely unlike list.

Comment: No, I don't need to because when I tried the program with vector, the program hung (briefly) when inserting items into the middle.

Comment: @EdwardBird What platform? Approximately how big is `A`?

Comment: Well then your objects must be huge, in which case I'd say use vector of pointers.

Comment: @aleguna, Yep, possibly over 10^5 objects. Pointers might be a good idea though.

Comment: But you said you had "over 500" items. 10^5 is slightly more than that. What is the size of one object?

Comment: @aleguna Each object is, err, 8bytes * 6, I think. I'm not responsible for that part of the code. When I say 500, that's what I've tested it at. (Actually I tested 5000 a second ago too, but that is besides the point.) I've been told that at some point we will be wanting to fit 10^5 objects in. Then once that's done with, we will go for 10^6 objects, and so on. (But the program will probably take weeks to run with that, so we may give up.)

Comment: @EdwardBird I don't agree with the 'wisdom'. You *can* learn about pointers and know whether you are doing it correctly. That's why you're asking us.

Comment: @PeterWood everyone makes mistakes and misunderstandings may occur. There is nothing wrong with checking you are correct.

Comment: @PeterWood: How does what you said relate to, or contradict, his quote?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley He is saying I should just "know" I am doing it correctly, which now I guess I do.

Comment: @EdwardBird, try vector with pointers. Also use `reserve` to reserve a sufficient space to prevent vector from reallocating itself. e.g. if you thing you'll have several 1000s objects do `v.reserve (10000)`

Comment: @aleguna That is probably a good idea as well, I will change the code.

Comment: @EdwardBird There is also the option to debug build the standard library (usually) to (try to) tell you when you do something incorrectly.

Comment: @AlexChamberlain, is this something to do with `-g` with GCC?

Comment: @aleguna Try vectors without pointers using reserve to prevent the vector reallocating itself.

Comment: @EdwardBird No, it is a macro depending on your `std` implementation. Always compile with `-g`, it enables debug symbols.

Comment: @AlexChamberlain, what if my supercomputer doesn't have a terrabyte of sequential ram? Mind you, a vector of pointers won't help much either.

Comment: why terabytes? 10^6 is just 1m  asuming you have 64bit OS, vector of pointers will be about 8MB that will easily fit into supercomputer's cache. Even if you don't use pointers 8*6*10^6 ~= 46MB  not that much either

Comment: @aleguna My computers CPU contains of the order 10^23 particles. The milky way contains of the order 300 billion stars. One needs a lot of ram, and one also needs to ensure the ram will allocate first time, because renting a super computer is expensive.

Comment: @aleguna I have no idea if we are doing stars or particles at the moment.

Comment: @EdwardBird, first it was 500, then 10^6, now it's 10^23. What next? You should have said it in the beginning that you need to handle 10^23 objects. Besides, searching for an element by index in the list which contains 10^23 objects is not just impractical, it's totally insane.

Comment: @aleguna Obviously that cannot be done - the point is it is an arbitrary size which will JUST fix into the ram until there is no (or little) free ram left!

Comment: If this is such a big issue, you need to write your own container. Also, you will hit other issues before trying to use the whole of RAM.

Comment: @EdwardBird, yes it can be done, otherwise scientists wouldn't have been able to model our universe. Or create games like Eve Online for that matter. You could use memory mapped files or sort of deque which would swap it's chunks on the disk when not used. There are many other solutions...

Comment: @aleguna I am a scientist. My task is to do it.

Comment: Tbh, I'm a little worried.

Comment: @AlexChamberlain Don't be we've simulated gravity before

Comment: @EdwardBird, he is worried because you don't seem to know what you are doing. You can't use the same techniques and data structures as you use for 10^6 elements to handle 10^23 elements, it isn't going to work.

Comment: @aleguna I guess I didn't think that far ahead yet. One step at a time. And I am fairly sure I can put 1.844674407×10¹⁹ items in a vector before I have problems on a 64 bit machine. (As far as I am aware.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes; you will return a reference inside the list if your function returns `A&` or `A const&` and a copy if your function returns `A`.

However, if you are doing this regularly, why not use a `std::vector`? They have random access iterators and are almost always more efficient than a `std::list`, unless the objects are large and you have a large number of them. `std::list` are very cache-inefficient.

Comment: Deliberately vague. The vector as a whole several times larger than cache size at a guess. It depends on whether you're using custom allocators too.

Comment: So if my objects are 100 bytes, that is "not large"?

Answer (score 1):

This is good as long as you have not advanced to (or past) end().

```
const A& stuff(std::list<A>& list_of_A, int index)
{
    assert(index <= list_of_A.size());              // Protect against UB
                                                    // of advancing past end.

    std::list<A>::iterator iter = list_of_A.begin();
    std::advance(iter, index);

    if (iter == list_of_A.end())
    {    throw std::runtime_error("Failed");       // Not allowed to de-reference end()
    }
    return *iter;
}
```